# QGIS crashes when deleting memory layer created by a script

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I wrote some scripts that create shapes based on different sources (Excel, XML...). 
These scripts follow the template on [Anita Graser's site](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/) and are integrated in my processing toolbox.

They work fine exploring, opening files and aggregating data as intended, and generating layers in memory.
Those layers can be saved and worked on.

But when I try to delete the generated memory layers, QGIS quits without an error message. I also can't use the "zoom to layer" function on these layers.

I may have forgotten something in my script but I can't find what.